# Efficient way to 'loop' in R

Tags: r

I'm new to R and I have this problem. I know I could make a loop, but I want to see if there is an R-ic method to do it.

I have data frame with values from 100 to 1000 in a column. I want to generate a table with the number of values less than 500, 600, 700, ..., 1000.

I know how to do:

```
x = seq(100, 1000, by=10)
y = seq(500, 1000, by=100)
sum(x<y[1])
```

I need to do something like:

```
sum(x<y)
```

that will return a vector with the counts.

I tried to look for similar questions, but it's a pretty nonspecific and I couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since , You can use `lapply` for example.

```
unlist(lapply(y, function(i) sum(x<i)))
```

It is the the R-idomatic manner to do a loop. It is basically a loop but with no side effect.

**EDIT**

I prefer using `table` here , and the R-ish `sapply` as suggested in the comment :)

```
sapply(y, function(i) table(x<i))
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
FALSE   51   41   31   21   11    1
TRUE    40   50   60   70   80   90
```

**EDIT**

you can also use `vapply` which is more safer since you specify the type of the retun as suggested by @flodel :

```
 vapply(y, function(i) sum(x<i), integer(1L))
```

Comment: Or just `sapply`.  But note that it's "R-ish" not "R-ic" :-)

Comment: shouldn't the number of counts be 40 50 60 70 80 90

Comment: @AdityaSihag I edit my answer in the same tuime you write the comment :)

Comment: @Ari - R-ic - was making a referral to 'pythonic' :) Anyway this is what I was looking for - it will just need to be sum(x<i) since I need the counts not the sum of the values. And    sapply shorthens it indeed.

Answer (score 1):

try out this

```
 sapply(y,FUN=function(iter) sum(x < iter))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
colSums(outer(x, y, '<'))
[1] 40 50 60 70 80 90
```

Comment: It's a memory hug. I would not recommend.

Comment: @flodel it is also slower.  But to me, it does look more idiomatic.